# Добавление шаблонного объекта

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Как в WordPress сделать панель добавления набора элементов div, которые будут находиться в одном целом div? Нужно сделать своеобразную форму, где заказчик уже сам сможет добавлять новые проекты в слайдер, и данные, которые он вписал, будут сами распределяться по заранее подготовленному шаблону такого проекта.

Подразумеваю это так:

```html
<div class="projects"> <!--Основной див-->
  
  <div class="project">
    <div class="project__label">Название проекта(сюда надо вставить данные, вписанные в форму, находяющуюся в панели WP)</div>
    <img class="project__img"> <!--Сюда то же, только фотографию, а не текст-->
    <div class="project__description">Описание проекта(то же самое, только с описанием)</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="project">
    <img class="project__img">
    <div class="project__label">Название проекта</div>
    <div class="project__description">Описание проекта</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="project">
    <img class="project__img">
    <div class="project__label">Название проекта</div>
    <div class="project__description">Описание проекта</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать плагин https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/. Создать поле repeater и в него добавить поле название, картинка и описание. Затем вывести это в шаблоне.

Так же вы можете обойтись без плагина, только еще вам нужно будет создать сам метабокс и написать хук на сохранение. Немного дольше, но идея такая же.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел подробное решение в этом видео

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ZgR8YSv864

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет)